# Wrap a JavaScript Promise to resolve to something different?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am new to Async JS.  I've added a function like the following to Firefox:

```
function addFoosToUrl(url, foos) {
    var promises = []
    foos.forEach(foo => {
        entry = { foo: foo, url: url }
        let promise = PlacesUtils.fooStuff.insert(entry)
        promises.push(promise)
    })

    return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

It works as expected.  The function `PlacesUtils.keywords.insert` inserts an entry into a database and returns a Promise that resolves to `null` when done.  So, as expected from [`Promise.all()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), my function returns a Promise after all entries have been inserted, resolving to an array of the resolved values from `PlacesUtils.keywords.insert`, which is: an array of nulls.

It seems like there should be a way to wrap `Promise.all()` so that the Promise I return resolves to something useful for chaining, such as, say, `url`.  Is there a neat way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chain a .then to the return Promise - like so

```
function addFoosToUrl(url, foos) {
    var promises = []
    foos.forEach(foo => {
        entry = { foo: foo, url: url }
        let promise = PlacesUtils.fooStuff.insert(entry)
        promises.push(promise)
    })

    return Promise.all(promises).then(() => url);
}
```

Or, more succinctly

```
function addFoosToUrl(url, foos) {
    return Promise.all(foos.map(foo => PlacesUtils.fooStuff.insert({ foo: foo, url: url }))).then(() => url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Promise.all() returns another promise object. It seems like, you can use .then chaining to get any thing you want from there.